# how to execute r script using postgres trigger

Tags: r, postgresql, triggers

I have a requirement where I want to call my rscript once i get a signal from outside which will be my triggering point.
for example:Once my table is updated with certain flag say 'Y',it should kick off my rscript.
I have also tried to refer the following link but still couldnt find suitable syntax on how we trigger the rscript.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154054/execute-r-script-using-a-postgresql-trigger